# How to bind an ip address to telnetlib in Python

Tags: python, ip-address, telnetlib

The code below binds an ip address to urllib, urllib2, etc.

```
import socket
true_socket = socket.socket
def bound_socket(*a, **k):
    sock = true_socket(*a, **k)
    sock.bind((sourceIP, 0))
    return sock
socket.socket = bound_socket
```

Is it also able to bind an ip address to telnetlib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`telnetlib` at least in recent Python releases uses `socket.create_connection` (see telnetlib's sources [here](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/telnetlib.py?revision=63788&view=markup)) but that should also be caught by your monkeypatch (sources [here](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/socket.py?revision=77263&view=markup) -- you'll see it uses a bare identifier `socket` but that's exactly in the module you're monkeypatching).  Of course monkeypatching is always extremely fragile (the tiniest optimization in some future release, hoisting the global lookup of `socket` in `create_connection`, and you're toast...;-) so maybe you'll want to monkeypath `create_connection` directly as a modestly-stronger approach.